# Excel Macro for processing radio buttons by cell

Tags: excel, vba

Im creating a macro in excel to process radio buttons by cell, while debugging and going step by step, it seems like the code ignores whether my radio button is true every time. Any pointers would be appreciated! Here is what I have so far: (To add on, I have the radio buttons in multiple cells, I changed the code here so I could test on a single cell)

```
Sub RadioController()

Dim total As Integer
Dim pass As Integer
Dim fail As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("L4")

    For Each cell In rng

        If radYes = True Then
            pass = pass + 1
            total = total + pass
        Else
            fail = fail + 1
        End If

    Next cell

    Range("K4") = total

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i guess you are using Active-X-Controls. You have to use the `Worksheets` Method to call your `OptionButton`. So if the Button is on the first `Worksheet` it would be:

```
...
    For Each cell In rng

        If Worksheets(1).radYes = True Then
            pass = pass + 1
            total = total + pass
        Else
            fail = fail + 1
        End If

    Next cell
...
```

Otherwise it handles `radYes` as Variable. If you use `F8` and hover over it, it should say that it is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Im using the regular form controls, I cant get activeX components to be selected ( The radio buttons wont check off when i click on them)